# Scheduling algorithm in linear complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here's the problem:

We have n tasks to complete in n days. We can complete a single task per day. Each task has a start date and an end date. We can't start a task before the start date and it has to be completed before the end date. So, given a vector `s` for the start dates and `e` for the end dates give a vector `d`, if it exists, where `d[i]` is the date you do task `i`. For example:

```
s = {1, 0, 1, 2, 0}
e = {2, 4, 2, 3, 1}

+--------+------------+----------+
| Task # | Start Date | End Date |
+--------+------------+----------+
|      0 |          1 |        2 |
|      1 |          0 |        4 |
|      2 |          1 |        2 |
|      3 |          2 |        3 |
|      4 |          0 |        1 |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

We have as a possible solution:

```
d = {1, 4, 2, 3, 0}

+--------+----------------+
| Task # | Date Completed |
+--------+----------------+
|      0 |              1 |
|      1 |              4 |
|      2 |              2 |
|      3 |              3 |
|      4 |              0 |
+--------+----------------+
```

It is trivial to create an algorithm with O(n^2). It is not too bad either to create an algorithm with O(nlogn). There is supposedly an algorithm that gives a solution with O(n). What would that be?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I've fooled around with the problem a bit with no success, but before I sink much more time into it I want an assurance that the problem actually **is**  known to have an O(n) solution. Do you have a source that claims an O(n) solution exists? Is preprocessing the data allowed? Is it supposed to be O(n) in the worst case or average case?

Comment: If one already knows that the travelling salesman problem is NP-hard (as it is), then the job-shop problem with sequence-dependent setup is clearly also NP-hard, since the TSP is special case of the JSP with m = 1 (the salesman is the machine and the cities are the jobs) and thus scheduling algorithms are NP-hard!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't be done faster than O(nlogn). Take the example where all jobs start on the first day, and their end dates are all unique and smaller than n, so for n=5 you have `s=[0,0,0,0,0]` and `e=[0,3,1,4,2]`. Clearly, the only way to schedule it is to complete the task ending soonest. But the only way I can think of doing so is to sort them, which is O(nlogn). Where did you read that this problem is solvable in O(n)? Are the input vectors sorted at all?

Answer (score 1):

When you can't use time, use space! You can represent the tasks open on any day using a bit vector. In O(n) create a "starting today" array. You can also represent the tasks ending soonest using another bit vector that can also be calculated in O(n). And then finally, in O(n) again scan each day, adding in any tasks starting that day, picking the lowest numbered task open that day giving priority to the ones ending soonest.

```cs
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Math;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 5;

        var s = new int[]{1, 0, 1, 2, 0};
        var e = new int[]{2, 4, 2, 3, 1};

        var sd = new int[n];
        var ed = new int[n];
        for (int task = 0; task < n; task++)
        {
            sd[s[task]] += (1 << task);  // Start for task i
            ed[e[task]] += (1 << task);  // End for task i
        }

        int bits = 0;

        // Track the earliest ending task
        var ends = new int[n];
        for (int day = n-1; day >= 0; day--)
        {
            if (ed[day] != 0)           // task(s) ending today
            {
                // replace any tasks that have later end dates
                bits = ed[day];
            }
            ends[day] = bits;
            bits = bits ^ sd[day];       // remove any starting
        }

        var d = new int[n];
        bits = 0;
        for (int day = 0; day < n; day++)
        {
            bits |= sd[day];              // add any starting

            int lowestBit;

            if ((ends[day] != 0) && ((bits & ends[day]) != 0))
            {
                // Have early ending tasks to deal with
                // and have not dealt with it yet
                int tb = bits & ends[day];
                lowestBit = tb & (-tb);
                if (lowestBit == 0) throw new Exception("Fail");
            }
            else
            {
                lowestBit = bits & (-bits);
            }
            int task = (int)Math.Log(lowestBit, 2);

            d[task] = day;
            bits = bits - lowestBit;      // remove task
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d));
    }
}
```

Result in this case is: 1, 4, 2, 3, 0 as expected.

Comment: What does the output array represent? It doesn't seem to match up with the expected output.

Comment: OK, it's the transpose. Easy to fix. Fixed.

Comment: That looks pretty close, but the last item seems off. 4 isn't a valid date for the last task.

Comment: FWIW, this is the same problem I was having with my attempt as well. I wrote a greedy algorithm using sets, which gives me {1,0,2,3,blank}, indicating there's no way to schedule these tasks. But of course, there is a way, it just doesn't find it because it greedily chose the wrong date for the second task.

Comment: Yes, tricky, not quite there... need to somehow use the end dates too. Thx.

Comment: A reverse scan can find the tasks ending soonest. Combining these two can then produce the correct result. Now I just need to check that this really does handle all cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75623/discussion-between-ian-mercer-and-asad).

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the name for such problems would be **Interval Scheduling.**

From your post, I assume that you are not looking for the Optimal Schedule and that you're simply looking to find any solution within O(n).

The problem here is that sorting will take O(nlogn) and computing will also take O(nlogn). You can try do it in one step:

Define V - a vector of 'time taken' for each task.

Define P - a vector of tasks which finish before a given task.
i.e if Task 2 finishes before Task 3, P[3] = 2.

Of course, as you can see the main computation is involved in finding P[j]. You always take the latest-ending non-overlapping task.

Thus, to find P[i]. Find a task which ends before the ith task. If more than one exists, pick the one which ends last.

Define M - a vector containing the resultant slots.

The algorithm:
    WIS(n)

```
M[0] <- 0
for j <- 1 to n
    do M[j] = max(wj + M[p(j)], M[j-1])
return M[n]
```

Comment: If the complexity of finding `P` is greater than constant time, doesn't that mean you can't do this in `O(n)`?

Comment: The Time complexity for the algorithm is O(n). Finding P is also O(n).

Comment: If the complexity of finding P is O(n), and the algorithm requires you to compute P_i for i in {1...n}, how could the algorithm also be O(n)? Or am I misunderstanding how many times you need to compute P?

Comment: You only compute P once.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. So each element in P is a vector of tasks? If so, could you show how this can be computed in O(n)?

Comment: To compute P[i] for each task:
Find a task which ends before task i.
If more than one exists, pick the one which ends last.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I can't see how you would compute `P[i]` in constant time. You'd have to examine all the other tasks, which is O(n), which accumulates to O(n^2) over the n indices of P.

Comment: I skimmed the link but I'm not sure what you want me to refer to there. The author is solving a completely different problem (interval scheduling maximization), and the final complexity of the dynamic programming solution is O(n logn).

Comment: Yes, in fact it is O(n logn). I'm not sure you can have an O(n) solution anymore. However, the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: The problem (at least the one described under the "Sample Problem" heading at the beginning) is different from this one. That one attempts to maximise the number of tasks completed, with all tasks non essential. It is an optimization problem. This one attempts to determine whether **any** schedule of tasks exists such that all tasks are completed with all constraints satisfied. Reducing one to the other is not trivial (at least to my knowledge), and if you have found a way to do it I would be very interested in seeing it in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Sort by end date, start date.  Then process data in sorted order only executing tasks that are after the start date.

Comment: @Asad - If you assume sorting using ordered comparisons, you're correct, but there are other ways to sort (depending on the data) that can achieve O(n). In this case, I'd suggest a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which I believe can be done in O(n) time in this case - though there's a a cheat there. The number of relevant digits in a date expressed as a day-number is O(log n) in the number of days/tasks, so the radix sort is arguably O(n log n) for this too.

Comment: @Asad - though on second thought, with O(n) space, you could use a base-n radix sort - one pass for start date (since that's the less-significant key, do that first) and one pass for end date. That's O(n) steps per pass, a constant number of passes, so it's O(n) overall.

Comment: @Steve314 For a fixed base, radix sort is O(dn), where d is the max number of digits in the input. Since the problem doesn't guarantee any upper bounds on the number of digits in the start day, so the complexity is unbounded here.

Comment: @Asad - the number of days is n and, so far as I can see, the range of days is contiguous. Therefore the day numbers are always in the range 0..n-1 - the number of base-n digits (for each date) is precisely one. All the zero digits above that one significant base-n digit are irrelevant. It's basically a bucket sort with n buckets, except we need two passes for the two dates which we handle the same way as for radix sort, hence treating each date as one digit.

Comment: @Asad - of course if you're really strict on the no-upper-bound-to-n, unbounded precision integers have log n digits so each operation on each date takes O(log n) time - simply looking at one date for all O(n) tass will take O(n log n) time.

Comment: @Steve314 I don't see where you're getting the days are contiguous. The second span for example is 0-4, could just as well have been 0-100000000.

Comment: @Steve314 "unbounded precision integers have log n digits" <-- Is n still the number of tasks here? If you're talking about n as the number of digits I agree, but we're still back where we started with the complexity being unbounded (solely) by the number of tasks.

Comment: @Asad - the question states "We have n tasks to complete in n days". The number of tasks and the number of days are the same thing.

Comment: @Steve314 That's because each task takes exactly 1 day. It doesn't mean the tasks must be completed over n consecutive days. The number of days between the completion of the first and last tasks is unbounded.

Comment: @Asad - my n tasks for n days comment referred to the O(log n) number of digits for O(n) distinct integers. For contiguity, I simply observe that the question uses contiguous day numbers for all examples. It's not proof, but it's amazing how often people forget to formally state all constraints they intend.

Comment: Either way, this is still O(n log n).  On radix sorting, Wikipedia explains "However, in general w cannot be considered a constant: if all n keys are distinct, then w has to be at least log n for a random-access machine to be able to store them in memory, which gives at best a time complexity O(n log n)"

Comment: @Ian Mercer - Wikipedia is assuming a constant base. I already stated that this is BASE N radix sort - each date is precisely one base n digit wide (assuming contiguous day numbers). One is a constant. In fact my first comment stated the O(n log n) - that was the general case, the O(n) was realizing this needn't be the general case.

Comment: @Steve314 I don't understand. How can the max number of digits in an arbitrary set of integers be bounded by log of the size of the set?

Comment: @Asad - Because in given j digits in base k, the largest integer you can represent is `(k^j)-1`. Logarithms are the inverse of powers. With this being a discrete case there's a `ceiling` in the actual inverse, but in asymptotic terms you just say the number of base k digits needed to represent a number in the range 0..n is bounded by log n - ie it's O(log n). k is independent of n, of course - the number of base n digits is still 1.

Comment: @Steve314 We're not talking about a number in the range 0-n. We're talking about n numbers in the range 0-infinity.

Comment: @Asad - so you assume and I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm simply speculating that perhaps that's not meant to be the case. You aren't OP, nor are you the person who assigned OP that problem. In any case, as I already said, if you assume n is 0..infinity then simply reading 1 date for all n tasks cannot be done in O(n) time. I got O(n log n) wrong, though - it's not an upper bound it's a lower bound, since by the pigeon whole principle the O(log n) refers to the **minimum** number of significant digits in the dates.

Comment: @Steve314 Unless a constraint is given in the problem, we can't assume such a constraint. That just seems like the reasonable convention to follow. I mean if I could make whatever assumptions I wanted the absurd extreme would be that I'd just assume that we're only dealing with an empty list of tasks and give an empty list as the solution.

Comment: @Asad - I'm not assuming a constraint, I'm speculating that it might exist. You're assuming that it's impossible for the question to be imperfectly stated.

Comment: You don't have to sort if you add items in the correct order.  Then you don't need to sort every time.  The insert function is only n/2.